# Disable tooltip select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

How to disable tooltip in select2? Is it work correctly in 4.06 version? I do not  want to hide it. I want to disable it. Now i only remove it on hover.

```
$(".raport_div").find('.select2-selection__rendered').hover(function() {$(this).prop('title', '');})
```

Comment: What do you mean with "disable the tooltip, not to hide"?

Comment: Add more code sample

Comment: I have a class which generates many selects. I want to use select 2 with they. That is the code which start select2. $( ".raport_div" ).find("select").select2(); I am searching for option which prevent select2 from creation title atribute in .select2-selection__rendered span.

Comment: The answer of @Gerfried seems to address your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the title to " ". This works in my test:
https://plnkr.co/edit/OG11it?p=preview

```
            {
                "id": "item1",
                "text": "item1",
                "title": " ",
            },
```

This is why it works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

> If this attribute is set to the empty string, it explicitly means its nearest ancestor's title is not relevant (and shouldn't be used in the tooltip for this element).

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer did not work for me
I removed the tooltip it by :

```
window.setTimeout(function() { $('.select2-result-label')
.children().removeAttr('data-content') }, 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply removed the title-attribute from the SPAN element.

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').each(
    function ()
    {
        $(this).on("mouseover",
            function ()
            {
                $(this).removeAttr("title");
            }                       
        );
    }
```

);